# Issue with named arguments being marked as an error in Intellij for Ruby 2.x

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine, ruby-2.1

Anyone else have a solution to this? IntelliJ freaks out when I use the new named arguments feature for ruby 2 in a method

```
def initialize(ini_url:, rundeck_url:, environment:, user:)
end
```

Or when calling a method supplying the named arguments

```
deploy_from_ini = DeployFromINI.new(ini_url: options[:ini_url],
rundeck_url: options[:rundeck_url],
environment: options[:environment],
user: options[:user])
```

This doesn't go away even if I set the project level SDK to ruby 2.1.4

I've upgraded to IntelliJ 14.0, upgraded to the latest ruby plugin (version 7.0.0.20141015) and still am getting red lines all over, which is highly irritating.
I've considered RubyMine but I've read that the plugin can lag behind RubyMine. Not sure if this would solve the issue and then I'd be introduced to the workflow of having to flip back and forth between RubyMine and IntelliJ, since the project I'm working on isn't fully ruby, just has ruby spattered across it in various places.

Comment: Works fine for me, although for Ruby 2.1.1.

Comment: In case you use Intellij IDEA (the last one 143.870) there was an issue for Ruby plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17327, which is fixed for the latest plugin version

If you use RubyMIne (the last version is 8.0.1) please check the language level for your Ruby SDK in Preferences

Comment: I confirm, named arguments don't work in RubyMine 6.0.4

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the answer you want but yes, RubyMine does understand named parameters (including the "required param" bare-colon syntax you showed above).